# How can i migrate SSL from Tomcat to Apache HTTPD?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I am migrating my single server tomcat to a cluster, load balanced and cached by Apache HTTPD (reverse proxy with mod_proxy).
Is it possible to convert the certificate and keys to the apache format or i have to re-issue the whole thing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's quite easy to extract the certificates directly with `keytool`, it's a bit trickier to extract the private key (although you could write programs to do so). I'd suggest using a combination of `keytool` and `openssl`.

If your keystore is in PKCS#12 format (.p12 file), skip this step. Convert your JKS store into a PKCS12 store using `keytool` (need version from Java 6+)

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore thekeystore.jks \
                        -srcstoretype JKS \
                        -destkeystore thekeystore.p12 \
                        -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Then, extract the certificate using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in thekeystore.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out servercert.pem
```

Extract the private key:

```
umask 0077
openssl pkcs12 -in thekeystore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out serverkey.pem
umask 0022
```

Note that, because the `-nodes` option is used when extracting the private key, the private key file won't be protected (as it mustn't have a password to be usable by Apache Httpd), so make sure no one else can read it.

Then, configure Apache Httpd using [`SSLCertificateFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) and [`SSLCertificateKeyFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatekeyfile) to point to the certificate file and the private key file, respectively.

Comment: -srsstoretype should be -scrstoretype

Comment: @jramoyo, thanks for spotting this typo. (You might have been able to suggest edits directly too.)

Comment: Unfortunately servercert.pem is empty (0bytes). Any hint?

Comment: @PeterRader Maybe your JKS store wasn't one with private keys in the first place, in which case converting it into PKCS#12 wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Ah, a jks must-not contain a private key! You made my day! Hey would you have a look at the installation's article of sotacms.com?

Comment: Could you explain how to exactly reverse the procedure: I have a working httpd ssl configuration: 1. SSLCertificateFile  certificate.cer, 2.  SSLCertificateKeyFile   privatekey.key 3. SSLCertificateChainFile   intermediate.cer. I need to create a java keystore (.jks) for vertx 3. All my attempts lead to  error: www.... uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER